# Calculate definite integral-2

Tags: definite-integrals

Why integral $I(b,x) = \int\limits_x^\infty  {{e^{ - ({y^2} + by)}}dy = \sqrt \pi  {e^{{b^2}/4}}N( - \sqrt 2  - b/\sqrt 2 )} $ where the function $N$ is deﬁned as $N(x)=\frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_{ - x}^\infty  {{e^{ - {y^2}/2}}dy = } \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_{ - \infty }^x {{e^{ - {y^2}/2}}dy} $

Comment: Hint: complete the square with $y^2+by$ and then make a change of variables to turn the nonconstant part into $u^2/2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you give me a bit more details, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the more general case
$$I= \int e^{-(a y^2+b y+c)}\,dy $$ As siad in comments, complete the square
$$ay^2+by+c=a \left(y+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$$
$$I=\exp\Bigg[\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a} \Bigg]\int \exp\Bigg[-a \left(y+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2\Bigg]\,dy$$
Let
$$y=-\frac{b}{2 a}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{a}}\implies dy=-\frac{dt}{ \sqrt{2a}}$$
$$\int \exp\Bigg[-a \left(y+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2\Bigg]\,dy=-\frac{1}{ \sqrt{2a}}\int e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt$$ Recombine everything to get $I$